# Why is it legal to define arbitrary return type of overloaded operators when T or T& is expected

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading

It is a spin off question from the example that Original Poster made in here: [Size of objects during Multilevel/Multiple inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21532144/unary-operator-overloading-prefix-postfix?noredirect=1#comment32516056_21532144). I hope this is valid to ask, and I could not find any info on this topic.

Can anyone tell why is this even legal to write stuff like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct A{
    int count = 0;
    void operator ++(){count++;};
    void operator ++(int){count++;};
    void operator =(int){};
};

int main() {
    A a;
    ++a;
    a++;
    a=5;
    std::cout << a.count;
    return 0;
}
```

This compiles with `g++ -std=c++11 -Wpedantic ./operator_overload.cpp` with no warnings at all. (c++11 is added for in-class initializer).

Why is it allowed by standard to return arbitrary types when a objects of the type of original class are expected on return, maybe they references.

My guess is that this allows writing of the expression types and implementation of the lazy evaluation and smart arithmetic optimizations for some classes and it would be hard to guess whether in the end the expression has sense type-wise. IMO it could be checked whether the resulting type of the expression can be casted to `T`, but I am not sure do not feel confident to make hard assumptions here.

But then I would still like to know why specifically `void` is allowed, as this seems completely nonsensical to me. Is there any use for it, or is this just left as is not to bloat standard or the compilers' codes?

Comment: Why shouldn't it be allowed? The standard never mentions that you cannot use specific return types in these cases. You want to shoot yourself in the foot? Do eet! Other than that, this question can only bring speculative answers and is therefore not suitable for SO (imho).

Comment: I know... well I guess. I know there are some exceptions that when you do not conform to the rules you can run into troubles. Why should it not be allowed. Because it makes no sense at all to have expectations of behaviour and not even warn that something makes zero sense. Maybe I asked a bad question. I do realize that banning everything that makes no sense is probably not most optimal way to go. My question is why it does not forbid "*obvious*" miss-use.

Comment: It's not obvious. There might some cases where you want a different behavior. It's like saying: "Passing by value is obviously wrong for class types, why does the compiler allow it when pass by constant reference is superior?". I think we all know the answer to that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like any other overloaded function, operator overloads are looked up by their name and parameter types; the return type is only relevant if the calling code uses it. There are no special rules to require them to act like the built-in operator, either in behaviour or return type.

Such a restriction would further limit the usefulness of operator overloading to define domain-specific syntax (such as `<<` and `>>` in the standard I/O library, and other (ab)uses in various popular libraries); some might argue that that's a good thing, but others would disagree, and the language doesn't judge.

The only exceptions are for operators used by language constructs, such as `->` and `new`, which must return the right type for expressions using them to be valid. Even then, as noted in the comments with an awesome example, there can be some flexibility in the return type.

Comment: So it basically is for the sake of freedom. I also like the point that it behaves like any other overload, meaning that return type does not matter.

Comment: Note that `->` does not have to return a pointer.  `ptr->x` is defined in-language, and for other types `a->x` is defined as `(a.operator->())->x`, which is quite slightly different than `operator->` must return a pointer. [collatz attack](http://ideone.com/pHLXL2)!

Answer (score 4):

A good (IMO) thing to remember is that it is called *operator overloading* because you overload the *meaning*, so that `++` doesn't necessarily need to have the same meaning as the builtin `++` operator.

*Expression template* libraries are an example where it is useful to be able to declare different return types.

Comment: I understand that you can freely change the meaning, but overload changing the return type kind of changes the valid syntax too. Doesn't it? I mean code that compiles can stop compiling when someone changes the return type of the operator. That is something more to me, than simply different behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

Because there is no real reason to forbid that usage. So they let programmer decide if that can be useful, the return type is not part of the overload resolution anyway.

template library like spirit use a lot of "hack" to implement parser directly in code with a EBNF-style grammar syntax and use that freedom.